# Millions of records in source(teradata) and generating files. Performance techniques?

Tags: informatica

My source is Teradata, joining multiple tables in between in the mapping and consists of multiple records(400 million records) generating a flat file with these many records. Its taking 18 hours for the mapping to run. DO we have any performance techniques in informatica power center so that they can run better?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Tejaswini.

Comment: First, take a look into the log file. Somewhere close to the end of it there is a section with performance summary. Please review or share here.

Comment: Hi can u help me in posting images in here. I am unable to post it.

Comment: Log text would be even better than image. Use some external service (pastebin, imgur) and share a link here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will be getting lots of bottle necks. You need to do use some of the techniques.

Increase performance in source,

- Make use of filter transformation right next to source qualifier
- Retrieve the source data by SQL query and check the time of execution in database itself

In the target,

- Network packet size of database can be increased
- Index and key constrainrs can be configured

In session,

- Make use of small cache size, lower buffer size and smaller commit intervals
- Make target load size as bulk

Answer (score 0):

Try push down optimization. Since your source are tables...let the joins happen on the db side and bring the least amount of data over to Informatica server.